# Xamarin Native Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets Error

Tags: xamarin.ios

I recieved the following build error for a Xamarin iOS project.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build490752 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/4.9.0.752/execute-task/AdvisedClient.iOS/a4a40d4002fACTool
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. AdvisedClient.iOS   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets 1206

The Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets file states clearly not to edit it. What gives?

Comment: Hi, please include your full build logs, crash reports (if any), test case (to reproduce) and all your version information.